# Manage multiple short-term tables with same schema or use single table for short-term data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My team has proposed to store session state data for each open client session in a table in the database.  The application server creates a new table for each client session as the user logs in via web browser.  The data that needs to be kept for the session is created along with the table, and is not modified (except in rare circumstances).  When the user logs out, the table is dropped.  Orphan tables are purged regularly.

The application server manages these short-term tables.  There won't be any database code that manages the tables or the data.

The data in these tables has relational links to other tables in the database.  The tables will be joined in queries to other tables in the database.

I'd like to find out the pro's and con's of this design, in contrast to others.  For example, all of the same functionality could be implemented in a single table that stored state data for all sessions.  If done this way, there would be one clustered index on the session ID.  Each access to the state data would read all of the data for exactly one session ID.

What are the scalability concerns for creating/dropping multiple tables rapidly?  Assume this occurs on the order of 1K-10K time per hour.

Comment: Has your team already considered and rejected #temp tables?

Comment: Using global temp tables might be practicable.  Let's assume for now that these short-term tables are in a user database.  The POC for this project uses a user database.

Comment: Web apps do not maintain connection to the DB, hence temp tables, local or global, are not an option. Is this IIS / ASP.NET? So far, I would lean towards a single SessionState table. Dropping and creating lots of tables will all hit the system catalog table(s) that manage the object meta-data. Adding and deleting data is meant to happen thousands of times per second (or more).

Comment: This is a Java application server.  It has a pool of threads that all need to have access to the table(s).  I thought a global temp table would support this.

Comment: Just use a single, permanent table with a key to each "pool." If a pool can't clean up its own threads leave some kind of trail behind so that a background job can help with cleanup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use the database to store session state? Is it for durability across app servers that can either go down or are load balanced?

Comment: Yes, for durability. Also because complex business logic is calculated at login, that governs how the user is allowed to interact with the rest of the system.

Comment: Jacob, please let us know which direction you decided to go in and why :)

Comment: Will do.  There will be a round of testing various designs first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much benefit of storing Web App Sessions per table:

- Creating and dropping tables is a little more expensive than inserting and deleting rows
- Depending on how many sessions can exist (current + inactive that have not been cleaned up yet), 10,000 tables is a bit more to deal with than 100,000 rows in a table
- Temp tables are not an option. http is a connectionless / stateless protocol, hence the need for sessions ;-). Since temp tables -- local and global -- are automatically dropped when the session in which they were created ends, they wouldn't persist between calls.
- Any app-based mechanism that can clean up obsolete tables can just as easily delete obsolete rows (i.e. an `OnSessionEnd` event and/or job that runs periodically).

IF, you are using ASP.NET, there is a somewhat built-in option to store Session State in SQL Server:

- [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)
- [Session Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478989.aspx)
- [Potential enhancements to ASPState](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/optimize-aspstate) (some tips from @Aaron B. to improve performance if you are using ASP.NET with the `SQLServer` Session-State mode)

That *might* work with JAVA / JSP, but probably not?

If not using ASP.NET, then you can:

- use a single table to store the serialized Session object. (this is one of the options mentioned in the question).
- OR, possibly use a cache server, such as **memcached**, **redis**, or even [Windows Server AppFabric Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx). They might be typically intended for longer-term caching, but I see some benefits to them, such as:

  - they are based in memory, not on disk (i.e. faster, which is why they exist in the first place)
  - they have built-in mechanisms for key expiration so you probably won't need app-based clean-up logic. Something to at least consider / look into.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to make Java use the session state database. The asp.net support is just a bunch of wrappers around stored procedure calls, no? Also it was one of the poster children for In-Memory OLTP ("Hekaton"), because durability is not important you could make the best use of that technology and benefit similarly to other in-memory technologies. I realize the OP is using 2005, but hopefully won't be forever, and other readers might find that angle useful.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The main benefit of the ASP.NET SQL Server option for Session handling is that it is built into the ASP.NET app server and completely transparent. The value of those objects is greatly diminished if one needs to update their app code to manage it. This is why I left it as a question as I haven't look into the various JAVA app servers to see if they can repoint their session handling. And In-Memory OLTP would be more viable if it weren't Enterprise-only. Session-handling alone wouldn't justify the cost. When that feature shows up in Express, then it will be an attractive option.

Comment: Well, I'm not suggesting go to Enterprise for that feature, especially if you'll only use it for session state. But if you're already on Enterprise (the OP hasn't said they're using Express, after all). Anyway, I'm just suggesting that in the right scenario you don't necessarily have to add layers to achieve the same types of efficiencies.

Comment: (As an aside, I've also blogged about [a series of enhancements to help ASPState scale better](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/optimize-aspstate), long before Hekaton details were made public.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, agreed that if they already have Enterprise, then using it in addition to making some/all of the changes you noted in that blog is definitely a viable option. But for non-ASP.NET I still think **memcached** and/or **redis** might be more appropriate. I did see a comment on your blog regarding someone using MS AppFabric Caching, which is the same concept, which I didn't mention because they were already using JAVA, but maybe worth a mention. I will update with that and the link to your blog with those tips.